# Video streaming and internet browsing on different bands/frequency

Tags: windows-7, bandwidth, wireless-networking

I have a Netgear WDNR37000 which allows clients on a 2ghz or 5ghz to access the internet and see every client and device on the network.  I have a computer with two nics, one that is in the 2ghz range and the other on the 5ghz range.
My specific problem is that I would like to serve my video streams (hulu, ps3mediaserver, playon) to my ps3 on the 5ghz band while internet browsing is routed to the 2ghz band.  This is so that the video streams aren't affected by general internet use.
While the easiest solution would be to disable internet access on the 5ghz apn, I would like to know of a solution that would not require that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you router, but generally how many adaptor's does you router have ? (How many antennas do you see ?) If it has two adaptors and the work seperately, you can do it. Otherwise (if you see only one antenna) you can't. But in any case, you can use some QOS parameters to give priority to your streamings.

Comment: The router has two radios (they don't show any antennas however).  I have yet to mess with the QOS parameters for it.  If I did, will it guarantee that that my computer with its dual-nic setup would push video to the 5ghz and general internet usage to the 2ghz radio?